# You can't go past without me about. Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> One can say that my words help you out,
>   or that you can't go past without me about.
>
> I may be old and rusty,
>   and phased out but I'm trusty!
>
> I was once on this site up above,
>   Gold, silver, or bronze that users love!
>
> Maybe I'm the turning point
>   that changed all history!
>
> *You just can't do without me!*

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're a

> Key

One can say that my words help you out,

> This could refer to the key on a map

or that you can't go past without me about.

> You can't go through a locked door without a key

I may be old and rusty,

> Keys get rusty.
>  [image: A rusted key.]

and phased out but I'm trusty!

> These days people might choose to use a keyless digital lock

I was once on this site up above,
Gold, silver, or bronze that users love!

> [image]

Maybe I'm the turning point
that changed all history!

> Could refer to a key event or key figure in history?

Comment: Good job! The only part you missed was why "I may be old and rusty," fits in to the key answer but I'll edit that in for you.